# Why Table is not being created in database using springboot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have created a new spring boot project. Every thing is fine with the project. The project also starts smoothly. But the table that should be created in the associated database is not being created. Given below is the source code that I have used:

The source code of application file is as follows

```
package personal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PersonalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersonalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/personal
spring.datasource.username=abc
spring.datasource.password=abc
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

Model

```
#imports
@Entity()
@Table(name="Registration_Table")
public class RegistrationModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int personId;
    private String personUsername;
    private String personPassword;
# getter
# Setter
}
```

Controller

```
# Imports
@RestController
@CrossOrigin

public class RegistrationController {
    
    @Autowired 
    private RegistrationServiceImplementation RegistrationServiceImplementation;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/save_person", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public String saveperson(@RequestParam("personUsername") String personUsername,
                             @RequestParam("personPassword") String personPassword)throws IOException {
        
        this.RegistrationServiceImplementation.savepersonprofile(personUsername, personPassword);
        
        return "Status Ok! Data Successfully saved!";
    }

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService implements RegistrationServiceImplementation{
    
    @Autowired
    private RegistrationDAO registrationDao;
    
    
    @Override
    public void savepersonprofile(String personUsername, String personPassword) {
        
        RegistrationModel registration = new RegistrationModel();
        registration.setPersonUsername(personUsername);
        registration.setPersonPassword(personPassword);
        
        registrationDao.save(registration);
    }

}
```

DAO

```
package personaldao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import personalmodels.RegistrationModel;


public interface RegistrationDAO extends JpaRepository<RegistrationModel, Integer>{

}
```

ServiceImplementation

```
package personalservices;

public interface RegistrationServiceImplementation {
    public void savepersonprofile(String personUsername, String personPassword);


}
```

Output after run

[image: Output After Program Execution]

Please let me know where I am doing the mistake. The program starts successfully. But the table is not being created.

Comment: Is the `Entity` in the same hierarchy as main class? Can you enable debug logs for `org.hibernate` and post them as well?

Comment: yes, the Entity is in the same hierarchy as main class

Comment: where is your RegistrationDAO class and also RegistrationServiceImplementation?

Comment: Its also in the same hierarchy.